# How can I prevent my Béarnaise sauce from thickening over night?

Tags: sauce

I'm sometimes making my own béarnaise sauce, and it tastes great and has perfect thickness the first day after making it. But whenever I leave leftovers in the fridge over night, the béarnaise gets really thick (like when whipping cream to much).

I'm trying to keep from overcooking my egg yolks, so I don't think that's whats wrong. I follow a pretty classic recipe with taragon, black peppercorns, white wine vinegar, shallots, egg yolks and clarified butter.

Is there a way to keep it from thickening like this when left in the fridge over night?

Comment: You can't.  But gently heating it while whipping in a small splash of water will restore it to it's former glory.  The stuff is similar in composition to a mayonnaise, and will thicken when cooled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the butter cools in the fridge.... It's going to thicken up. I can't see a way around this? When you heat it up again, it should return to consistency...

Comment: Ofcourse, why didn't I realize that? :) Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe using some kind of oil (like rapeseed or olive oil) could work as good as the clarified butter, and still keep the souce from thickening when cooled. What do you think?

Comment: Well... I think that's certainly a good way to fight off the thickening (although it will still thicken - just not as much). However (and it's a big however) it won't taste anywhere close to as good. But if your biggest issue is that the sauce needs to be as close to original consistency, sometimes you just have to sacrifice...

Comment: Hehe, no obviously taste is the most important factor in this case. I was just trying to come up with a way to get both. Since the sauce you buy in stores does not thicken I thought maybe there would be such an easy solution as using oil instead of butter.